# ffmpeg converting to mp4 without audio

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have a form that supposed to upload video and convert any uploaded video format to mp4.
The issue is, when i tried to upload a video from iPhone .mov it is converted successfully but without audio

HTML:

```
<form action="https://propeview.com/wp-includes/video/process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" size="1040" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-drag-n-drop-file d-none" aria-invalid="false" multiple="multiple" name="file" id="file" data-limit="200000000" data-max="1" data-id="9015" accept=".">
 
  
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload video" class="wpcf7-form-control has-spinner wpcf7-submit btn color-bg">
</form>
```

PHP: process.php

```
<?php 
$uploads_dir = 'original/';
$file_name = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$output_name = explode('.', $file_name)[0];
$uploaded_file = $uploads_dir . $file_name;
$convert_status = ['mp4' => 0];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploaded_file)) {
    // Make sure to get the correct path to ffmpeg
    // Run $ where ffmpeg to get the path
    $ffmpeg = '/bin/ffmpeg';
    
    // MP4
    $video_mp4 = $output_name . '.mp4';
    exec($ffmpeg . ' -i "' . $uploaded_file . '" -vcodec h264 -an -acodec aac -an "./converted/' . $video_mp4 . '" -y 1>convert.txt 2>&1', $output, $convert_status['mp4']);

    // Debug
    // echo '<pre>' . print_r($output, 1) . ' </pre>';

    // WebM
    $video_webm = $output_name . '.webm';
    exec($ffmpeg . ' -i "' . $uploaded_file . '" -c:v libvpx -c:a libvorbis -an "./converted/' . $video_webm . '" -y 1>convert.txt 2>&1', $output, $convert_status['webm']);

    // Debug
    // echo '<pre>' . print_r($output, 1) . ' </pre>';
  }
}
?>
```

When i tried to test the conversion on SSH by runing the comand

```
wget https://filesamples.com/samples/video/mov/sample_960x400_ocean_with_audio.mov;
ffmpeg -i sample_960x400_ocean_with_audio.mov -vcodec h264 -acodec aac test_converted.mp4
```

It gave me the below error:

```
[aac @ 0x17332e0] The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
[aac @ 0x17332e0] Alternatively use the non experimental encoder 'libfdk_aac'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a shell script and used another command to create the mp4 (with audio):

### test.sh

```sh
wget https://filesamples.com/samples/video/mov/sample_960x400_ocean_with_audio.mov;
ffmpeg -i sample_960x400_ocean_with_audio.mov -vcodec h264 -acodec aac test_converted.mp4
```

Run

```sh
source ./test.sh
```

Now open `test_converted.mp4` to check the audio.

### The php script

Change the following line

```php
exec($ffmpeg . ' -i "' . $uploaded_file . '" -c:v libx264 -an "./converted/' . $video_mp4 . '" -y 1>convert.txt 2>&1', $output, $convert_status['mp4']);
```

To

```php
exec($ffmpeg . ' -i "' . $uploaded_file . '" -vcodec h264 -acodec aac  "./converted/' . $video_mp4 . '">convert.txt 2>&1', $output, $convert_status['mp4']);
```

Comment: when we changed the PHP code the file stile without audio and it give me an error when converting.

Comment: Do we need to do anything on the SSH.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: We changed the code to 
exec($ffmpeg . ' -i "' . $uploaded_file . '" -vcodec h264 -an -acodec aac -an "./converted/' . $video_mp4 . '" -y 1>convert.txt 2>&1', $output, $convert_status['mp4']);
It is now converting but it still without audio

Comment: strange, I cannot reproduce with the code I provided. Maybe you can try to reinstall ffmpeg?

Comment: I did reinstall it and it is converting: the ssh test output :"anaconda-ks.cfg  original-ks.cfg  sample_960x400_ocean_with_audio.mov    test_converted.mp4
cpanel3-skel     perl5            sample_960x400_ocean_with_audio.mov.1  tmp"
I think the issue with the PHP code but i still cannot figure out what is causing the issue

Comment: when i tried to test the SSH code you gave to me to convirt the file it gives me the following error
'''[aac @ 0x17332e0] The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.

[aac @ 0x17332e0] Alternatively use the non experimental encoder 'libfdk_aac'.'''

Comment: I have updated the question, please check it

Comment: I think replacing aac with libfdk_aac in the command will work in your case.

Comment: In the comand line we have no issue now when used:

Comment: wget https://filesamples.com/samples/video/mov/sample_960x400_ocean_with_audio.mov; ffmpeg -i sample_960x400_ocean_with_audio.mov -vcodec h264 -acodec libfdk_aac test_converted.mp4

Comment: The issue is still with the PHP code, it is still converting without the sound

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239126/discussion-between-douma-and-john-adams).

Comment: It is now working with your solution, just we need to change acc to be libfdk_aac

Comment: Is it possible to add a watermark to the video through this code?